# How to pass Special characters to JavaScript in JSP..?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

i know that there is an function Escape() in javascript, escapeXml in JSTL, i  used several ways for solving this thing but didnt get the solution.
The problem is ..

the JSTL variable suppose say ${str} has value "system # with ^%$ / <".

i pass this value to javascript as OnClick="special('${str}')"

i get an error as:-

`Error: unterminated string literal
Source File: http://localhost:8080/..
Line: 1, Column: 27
Source Code:
special('system # with ^%$ / <`

I am not able to pass the string is itself to javaScript.

PS : i copied the above error statement from mozilla error console.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to escape the double *and* single quotes in the string. I'd do this with a function you define, rather than [`fn:replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) because the quoting is kind of gnarly.

The simplest way to do this is to use the Apache [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeJavaScript()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) function.

> Escapes the characters in a `String` using JavaScript String rules.
>
> Escapes any values it finds into their JavaScript String form. Deals correctly with quotes and control-chars (tab, backslash, cr, ff, etc.)
>
> So a tab becomes the characters `'\\'` and `'t'`.
>
> The only difference between Java strings and JavaScript strings is that in JavaScript, a >single quote must be escaped.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> input string: He didn't say, "Stop!"
> output string: He didn\'t say, \"Stop!\"
> ```

So your servlet could do this:

```
request.setAttribute("str",
    StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript("\"system # with ^%$ / <\""));
```

Then your JSP can simply contain:

```
... onclick="'${str}'" ...
```

You could create a custom EL function to do this as well (using the same `escapeJavaScript()` function underneath) but that is more complicated.

Comment: matt the thing is i am passing the entire collection from controller. so ${str} is a jSTL variable, how can i use it in scriptlet tag to set in the request attribute..?

Comment: @ayyappa: aha! In that case, you should create an EL function. Good, short instructions of how to do that [here](http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/). Oracle docs [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp77078).

Comment: @ayyappa: no. That's a JavaScript function, and doesn't do what you need to do anyway.

Comment: Hey folks..

i finally resolved this issue using spring message tag, giving javaScriptEscape="true"

after 3 weeks of research !!

<spring:message code="${escapedString}" javaScriptEscape="true"/>

Comment: Note that in commons-lang 3.x, this has been renamed to `escapeEcmaScript`